# How to use cookie and BASIC authentication together?

Tags: scala, spray

I am using a combination of cookie and basic authentication. In the basic authentication, it takes a function

```
Option[UserPass] => Future[Option[T]]
```

and returns a `Directive[T]`.

I wish to create a directive on cookie which takes a function

```
HttpCookie => Future[T]
```

and returns a `Directive[T]`.

Hence I can do a combined auth directive of `cookieAuth | basicAuth`.

The closest I could get is:

```
def myFunction:HttpCookie => Future[String]

val cookieAuth:Directive[String] = cookie("MyCookie").flatMap { cookie =>
  onSuccess(myFunction(cookie))
}
```

But the signatures do not match. I get the exception:

```
type mismatch;
  found   : spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]
  required: spray.routing.Directive[String]
         ^
```

Comment: And why not to return `Directive[Future[T]]`? If you want to return a `Directive[T]` from `Future[T]`, it's a blocking operation which is very bad

Comment: And for `Future` there is a `CompletionMagnet` or `onSuccess` directives which can handle it

Comment: So is the out of the box, authenticate with basic authentication method blocking?  It takes a Future[Option[T]] and returns a directive [T].  Based on that I was assuming directives might, by nature be non-blocking.

Comment: Didn't find what you mean in spray lib. Can you show some link?

Comment: http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/security-directives/authenticate/#authenticate

Comment: Also in my example I did use the onSuccess directive that you mentioned, couldnt get the signature to match though.  Kind of new to this directive business

Comment: You example `cookieAuth` should work, signature is correct and what's the problem?

Comment: And no, spray authentication is not blocking, they are just wrapping inner Route in onSuccess Directive

Comment: Oh, i see, just change to `val cookieAuth: Directive1[String]`, don't miss number `1` in `Directive1`, Directive itself takes type parameters with upper bound `HList`

Comment: thanks, did, also i've just wrote a little [post](http://alterstack.io/blog/2013/10/02/binding-directives-in-spray) on spray directives and scalaz, which might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** Make the result of type `Directive1[String]`.

The initial problem was in a type mismatch. The pure `Directive` trait takes type parameter with an upper bound of `HList` so the result type was based on Shapeless's `HList` `Directive[String :: HNil]`.

In `routing` package object declared to type alises for `Directive[HNil]` and `Directive[T :: HNil]`, `Directive0` and `Directive1[T]`, respectively.